# Can I disable iMessage on an a computer I no longer have access

Tags: icloud, messages

I recently left my ex, he still has access to my iMessages on the Mac we shared. How can I remotely disable his access to my messages?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to change your [Apple ID password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201355).

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz Thanks for the comment. Feel free to update the answer. However, I am not 100% sure if this is the case. Last time I changed the password all messages disappeared. Physically they will probably remain on the Mac.